# Unity 5 portrait view camera settings

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have some doubts regarding unity portrait settings ; whats the best background image size to set for portrait window on Android to appear clear in all resolutions? Also, how do we set/tilt camera for portrait view? For now, the camera is still set in the landscape even after setting the project and scene for portrait in player settings...please help.

Comment: For unity-related questions you might want to try here as well: http://answers.unity3d.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have asked multiple questions. I answer your first question: It depends on your image. You can try these two approaches and see which one looks better:

1. Use a `3840 × 2160` image (That's 4K). It's as simple as that but it may appear pixellated on small screens if it contains small details.
2. Use a `2048 × 2048` image (That's a high resolution POT) and enable mipmaps in import settings. This way it doesn't appear pixellated on small screens. But it maybe stretched a little on screens with different aspect ratios. You must also set these settings for the second approach:

set borders in sprite editor:

[image]

set rect transform values and image values in UI:

[image]